# Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable - what if I want multiple enumerations?

Tags: c#, list, resharper, ienumerable, multiple-instances

I have a method that creates a file structure, and uses this file structure in multiple instances of view models. So in this case, let's say a Question or an Answer will both have an instance of a list of "files" that they point at, and each Question/Answer can modify it's own instance.

Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
public void GeneratVms()
{
   List<IFile> files = _data.GetFiles();
   IEnumerable<IFileViewModel> fileVms = _generator.GenerateFileList(originalFileList);

   MyQuestionController = _generator.GenerateQuestionController(_questions, fileVms);
   MyAnswerController = _generator.GenerateAnswerController(_answers, fileVms);
}
```

And then the Question/Answer controller generators look like this:

```
public IQuestionController GenerateQuestionController(
            List<IQuestion> questions, IEnumerable<IFileViewModel> files)
{
      IEnumerable<IQuestionViewModel> questionVms = 
                questions.Select(q => new QuestionViewModel(q, files));

      // Pass through these questions to the controller, and also the 
      // original file list, so the controller can create new instances 
      // of QuestionViewModel which will also have the file structure.
      return new QuestionController(questionVms, files); 
}
```

There is currently no problem with this an it works as intended. However, ReSharper complains that there may be "possible multiple enumerations of IEnumerable". This leads me to believe that maybe I'm not being explicit with what I'm doing?

If I handles fileVms as a List, then every instance I pass to the various Questions/Answers is treated as the same, so they cannot keep their own unique version of the "list", if you like.

Can anyone provide a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

This warning appears because `fileVms` is an `IEnumerable<T>`. Although the runtime-type if this instance might be `List<T>` ReSharper cannot make any assumptions on this and thus returns the message.

However you can simply avoid this by changing the type of `fileVms` to `List<T>` instead.

As your method `GenerateFileList` you could simply ignore the warning also. However consider this implementation:

```
public IEnumerable<IFileViewModel> GenerateFileList(originalFileList) {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(new FileModel));
}
```

This method does return an iterator instead of an actual list. Thus when you provide its return-value to another method twice you´d iterate this iterator twice as well. So when you call

```
IEnumerable<IQuestionViewModel> questionVms = 
    questions.Select(q => new QuestionViewModel(q, files));
```

within your `GenerateQuestionController`-method and afterwards

```
IEnumerable<IAnswerViewModel> answerVms = 
    answers.Select(a => new AnswerViewModel(a, files));
```

in `GenerateAnswerController` you´ll iterate the `files`-parameter twice and therefor run the `GenerateFileList`-method twice as well.

Comment: Yes, but if I change fileVms to a List<T> then it behaves differently - the instance is cemented, and when an instance of a Question updates a File, this update is reflected throughout. I don't want this to happen, I'd rather pass a new instance of each file list to each Question - hence keeping it an IEnumerable. My question was more to do with how I make this more explicit?

Comment: @jimbo How about use `IList<T>` instead?  I think that's about as explicit as you can get without re-architecting.

Comment: I can´t see why a question should updates a file within a list. Where does this happen? Furthermore: what exactly does `GenerateFileList` actually return? A list or an iterator?

Comment: Wouldn't IList<T> cause the same issue?

And GenerateFileList returns an IEnumerable<IFileViewModel>. Effectively, I want a "Question" (etc) to be able to modify individual file list - update those IFileViewModel items however it likes - without that affecting the status of the same IFileViewModel in another Question's list.

Comment: If the actual list might change in the meanitime you have of course to re-iterate the list. In this case you may either ignore the warning or suppress it with a comment as this is intended behaviour.